# Swift Language: Updating Parse objects

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode6, pfobject

Good evening Coders!

I created a query that gets the username and location of people around me within 7miles of device location, I would like to update these objects every 5-10seconds(I haven't decided yet). What would be the best practice for this? should i create an `NSTimer()` and call it that way? please help!!

```
 var timer = NSTimer()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    timer == NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self,            selector: "queryFunc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
  }

  func queryFunc() {

    var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")

    query.whereKey("playerName", equalTo:"Sean Plott")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {

      (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

      if error == nil {

       // The find succeeded.

       NSLog("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) scores.")

       // Do something with the found objects

       for object in objects { NSLog("%@", object.objectId)

       }

     } else {

       // Log details of the failure

       NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo!)

    }

  }

  /*

  This is just an example query, the point of this is the timer and how to update objects periodically

  */

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add whereKey:nearGeoPoint:withinMiles: in your query which will find objects within 7 miles from your location

[For further details for that check out this link](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/whereKey:nearGeoPoint:withinMiles:)

and when you found data after each query then remove all previous data and replace it with new data and refresh your view.

**NSTimer is probably the Good Option go for it. Even I also have used timer to sync in background in every 5 min and it's working fine for me.**

Hope this will help you.

Comment: The query I'm using does all of that, i just used an example query from parse, the point of my question is how i should update my objects periodically, should i create a timer and update them that way? or is there a more practical way?